# How to Remove Bracketed Text & Brackets?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to remove these two values in a new Google Data Studio Custom Dimension:

```
[BMM]
```

```
[EM]
```

A RegEx that removes the entire bracketed text of any text would also suffice if easier.

Answer (score 1):

The [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below captures all `.*` the values between `[` and `]` (where `Field` represents the respective field):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Field, "(\\[.*\\])", "")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1af06077-4cfb-4529-8123-b9a908aac2c2), as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 3]]